# How do I write " inside a string? Objective C

Tags: objective-c

How can I write a `"` inside an Objective-C string?

For example I have the

```
NSString *sql= @"select * from test where name="name"";
```

Comment: What database are you using? Most databases use `where name='name'`, not `where name="name"`.

Comment: SQLite. Actually I tested both ways in the terminal and they both return value. I'll just write it like that, but for my general knowledge it would still be good to know how to escape that character

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\"`. In your case it would be:

```
NSString *sql= @"select * from test where name=\"name\""
```

Answer (score 0):

say you have string like `@"abc"def"123";`
do it like `@"abc\"def\"123";`

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString* name = @"Jason";
NSString* selectStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from foo where name = \"%@\"", name];
```